# Rust giving unknown error and can not determine what to fix in code

Tags: parsing, rust, type-conversion, runtime-error

I am new to Rust and i am trying to build a something to convert hours and secs to a total amount of mins, but it is giving me this error which I do not know what to do with

`thread 'main' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: ParseFloatError { kind: Invalid }', src/main.rs:22:39 stack backtrace:`

Here is the code for the script:

```
//geting user input
let mut line = String::new();
println!("Enter your hours:miniuts:seconds... ");
std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
//spliting string to get hours minutes seconds as different entries in this var
let h_m_s: Vec<&str> = line.split(':').collect();

//convert array to seperate vars
let hours_str = h_m_s[0].to_string();
let mins_str = h_m_s[1].to_string();
let sec_str = h_m_s[2].to_string();

//convert str to int
let hours = hours_str.parse::<f32>().unwrap();
let mins = mins_str.parse::<f32>().unwrap();
let secs = sec_str.parse::<f32>().unwrap();

//now converting to minutes nearing the two decimal places (you know hopefully:))
let hours_to_min = hours * 60.00;
let secs_to_min = secs / 60.00;
let final_result = hours_to_min + mins + secs_to_min;
println!("Here are the minutes: {:.2}", final_result);
```

I have tried looking it up but nothing comes up that is use-full in my use case.

I also have determined that it is the `let secs = sec_str.parse::<f32>().unwrap();`  var that is the problem but i am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

The `ParseFloatError { kind: Invalid }` could happen because the string you are trying to parse as a `f32` is not valid, for example an empty space at the end of the seconds, like in your case.

To avoid this error, trim the variables and use the parse method with a Result return type and handle the error gracefully, for example:

```
fn main() {

    //geting user input
    let mut line = String::new();
    println!("Enter your hours:miniuts:seconds... ");
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
    //spliting string to get hours minutes seconds as different entries in this var
    let h_m_s: Vec<&str> = line.split(':').collect();

    //convert array to seperate vars
    let hours_str = h_m_s[0].to_string();
    let mins_str = h_m_s[1].to_string();
    let sec_str = h_m_s[2].to_string();
    let s: String = sec_str.to_string();
    let sec_str = s.trim();

    println!("Hours: {}, Minutes: {}, Seconds: {}", hours_str, mins_str, sec_str);

    let hours = match hours_str.parse::<f32>() {
        Ok(hours) => hours,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Invalid input for hours");
            return;
        }
    };
    
    let mins = match mins_str.parse::<f32>() {
        Ok(mins) => mins,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Invalid input for minutes");
            return;
        }
    };
    
    let secs = match sec_str.parse::<f32>() {
        Ok(secs) => secs,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Invalid input for seconds");
            return;
        }
    };

    //now converting to minutes nearing the two decimal places (you know hopefully:))
    let hours_to_min = hours * 60.00;
    let secs_to_min = secs / 60.00;
    let final_result = hours_to_min + mins + secs_to_min;
    println!("Here are the minutes: {:.2}", final_result);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got the same error as before. what i used as the input was "1:2:3" what would you think the type error is coming from? Thanks for the help.

Comment: the problem is that for the seconds you need to trim the text, I edited the code in my answer with the needed changes :)